# How to set custom installation directory for a java application that is installed by a packaged installer(created with Jpackage)?

Tags: java, installation-package, jpackage, installation-path

I packaged my java app using jpackage. When I install it with the packaged installer, the directory after the installation is always `C:\Program Files\<program name>`.How do I change it?

Let me clarify once more, that I am not talking about the output directory where the packaged installer's exe file should be located once the packaging is done. I am talking about the directory where that packaged installer exe extracts its content after double-clicking it, which is by default `C:\Program Files\<program name>.`

Regards,

Fida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `--win-dir-chooser` parameter. Reading the documentation for jpackage or using `jpackage --help` would get this answer this faster than you can type this question on Stackoverflow!

Comment: Well, thanks. I did look into the documentation but don't know how I missed this one. Would you please help me with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68067908/) as well? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Someone beat me to it - hopefully you're OK now. This may also help you when re-installing so that the previous version uninstalls itself each time: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675323/cannot-rerun-java-jpackage-installer-if-already-installed-second-time-just-exit/62819060#62819060]

Comment: Yeah! [This man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3699139/jorn-vernee) already saved me before you arrived. I became quite frustrated after that problem. And thanks for the extra tip; this is very useful as well (probably within a day or two I was going to post that question too in StackOverflow because I don't usually expect such questions to already exist).