# Java program that is installed by a packaged installer (created with jpackage) runs in the background(doesn't open any window) - bug

Tags: java, windows-installer, background-process, jpackage

I am new to java. Before I get straight to the point, let me introduce to you where I currently am. Sorry for the long story.

I made a packaged installer for my app with jpackage. I packaged a simple hello world program for the first time, just to test the jpackage command. Once it produced the packaged installer, I installed my hello world program with it.

Then I went to `C:\Program Files\Hello World` and then executed the `HelloWorld.exe` file.; but nothing happened. To debug the issue, I rebuilt the HelloWorld.jar file with an infinite loop at the end. Then I repackaged and reinstalled the program again. Then I ran the HelloWorld.exe again.

However, this time I saw a blue circle at my mouse's cursor for quite some time. So I opened task manager scrolled down, and then I found the HelloWorld program running in the list of background processes! Here is a screenshot:

[screenshot of task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouwbn.png)

So, this is my question: Why is my java application, which I created with a packaged installer created by packaged, running in the background? Why isn't it opening any console windows?

EDIT: I forgot to include the command that I used to create my packaged installer. Here it is:

```
jpackage -t exe --name HelloWorld --input D:\Fida\Codeblocks\Java\Projects\HelloWorld\dist --dest D:\Fida\CodeBlocks\java --main-jar HelloWorld.jar --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\jmods" --add-modules java.base --description "Hello World Program" --app-version 1.0.0 --vendor Fida --icon D:\icon_file.ico --copyright Fida --win-shortcut --win-menu
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for a console to be shown when running the application, you must add the `--win-console` option when invoking `jpackge`:

```
Platform dependent option for creating the application launcher:
  --win-console
          Creates a console launcher for the application, should be
          specified for application which requires console interactions
```

Comment: I should have read the documentation of jpackage completely before I asked this question. It works!